# Duration of warm up during workout

Tags: workout-routines

How much warm up is supposed to be done?  And for how much time? I workout for two hours but adding the warm up makes it very exhausting. How much time should be spent on warm up?

Is it necessary to do stretching after workout as well? 
Is it ok to skip warm up?
My age is 19 years.  Will not doing warm up affect my performance as I grow old?
Is it also necessary to warm up with a lighter weight before starting with a heavier one?
Does it really help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you want to warm up is to loosen up your muscles and raise your heart rate a little bit.

If you're going with the cardio way of warming up, typically you would get to the point where you start to break a sweat and maintain it for at least 5 minutes.

[Warm Up, Cool Down](http://www.heart.org/HEARTORG/HealthyLiving/PhysicalActivity/FitnessBasics/Warm-Up-Cool-Down_UCM_430168_Article.jsp)

> **Warm up**
>
> Before you exercise, think about warming up your muscles like you would warm up your car. It increases the temperature and flexibility of your muscles, and helps you be more efficient and safer during your workout.  A warm-up before moderate- or vigorous-intensity aerobic activity allows a gradual increase in heart rate and breathing at the start of the activity.
>
> **Tips:**
>
> - Warm up for 5 to 10 minutes. The more intense the activity, the longer the warm-up.
> - Do whatever activity you plan on doing (running, walking, cycling,
>   etc.) at a slower pace (jog, walk slowly).
> - Use your entire body

---

If you're talking about weightlifting warm-ups, then typically start light and work your way up. For example, I start squatting with the bar do a set of 10, slowly add a 25lbs plate on each side until I am sweating (No breaks). After I break a sweat, I keep adding 25lbs, but I lower the amount of reps (1-5) until my working set.

The reason I keep adding weight slowly is to prevent injuries. They give you feedback on your form or your mood and boost your confidence. For myself, I never look forward to leg day. However, once I start squatting, I remember just how much I love leg day and why it's my favorite day...

---

As for stretching, you don't need to stretch, some people do just fine without stretching... But later on in life, it might affect your mobility. Prevention is the best treatment. These don't have to be done right after your workout, but it is the best time to do so. You can do them first thing in the morning, last thing before you go to bed, it doesn't matter much.

[Do I need to stretch before exercising?](http://www.nhs.uk/Livewell/fitness/Pages/Do-I-need-to-stretch-before-or-after-a-run-or-sports-and-exercise.aspx)

> There is some evidence that regular static stretching outside periods of exercise may increase power and speed, and reduce injury. The best time to stretch is when the muscles are warm and pliable. This could be during a yoga or pilates class, or just after exercising.